# Bouncy Castle Export method in C# returns different size byte arrays in .NET 3.5 and 4.5

Tags: c#, .net, encryption, bouncycastle

I have to maintain software using the crypto.dll from Bouncy Castle. The software is used for encryption and decryption of certain data coming from an instrument.  The Visual Studio (2013) solution consists of two projects, both written in C#.  The application creates certificates (.cer) and personal information exchange format (.pfx) files. When the project settings are set to target .NET 3.5 the size of the .pfx file is 3 kb and it works fine, meaning the encrypted data is decrypted, provided the certificate has been installed. When the project is set to target .NET 4.5 (or 4.6), the size of the .pfx file is 2 kb and the encrypted data files cannot be decrypted. I was able to track the difference to the method Export(X509ContentType contentType, string password) of the cX509Certificate class. This method returns a byte array with a size of 2.6 kB in .NET 3.5 and 1 kB in .NET 4.5. Has anybody seen this behavior? Is there a work around?

Comment: This is known Bug -> http://www.bouncycastle.org/jira/browse/BMA-138

Comment: Oops... It turns out the Export method has nothing to do with the Bouncy castle crypto.dll.  It is a System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate method. So this looks like a .NET problem.